# Why use do { } while (0) in macro definition?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, libev

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are there sometimes meaningless do/while and if/else statements in C/C++ macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-are-there-sometimes-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-mac)

I met code like below:

```
#define ev_io_init(ev,cb,fd,events) \
do { \
  ev_init ((ev), (cb)); \
  ev_io_set ((ev),(fd),(events)); \
} while (0)
```

I want to know why the author use `do { } while (0)` here.
Is there any difference with this?

```
#define ev_io_init(ev,cb,fd,events) { \
  ev_init ((ev), (cb)); \
  ev_io_set ((ev),(fd),(events)); \
}
```

BTW: the code is from libev, ev_local.h

Answer (score 34):

Consider `if( something ) function1(); else function2();`

If `function1()` is actually a macro, just using `{ }` requires you to omit the semicolon at the point of use, but `do { } while(0)` lets you use exactly the same syntax as for a real function.

(Not using any kind of block construct at all would just generate completely broken code, natch)

Answer (score 24):

Enclosing code with a loop allows for a preprocessor directive to execute multiple statements without "breaking" if-else-constructs. Consider the following:

```
#define DO_SOMETHING() a();b();c();

void foo()
{
    // This is ok...
    DO_SOMETHING();
}

void bar()
{
    // ...whereas this would trigger an error.
    if (condition)
       DO_SOMETHING();
    else
       blah();
}
```

The second example breaks the if-else-construct because three statements are followed by an `else` clause. To allow for it to correctly substitute, the instructions in `DO_SOMETHING` should be enclosed with a `do { ... } while(0)`.

Comment: of course, if you use naked if lines like that, you deserve for your code to break...

Comment: @Simon But doesn't linux kernel coding style advice us to use naked if else lines for one line block?

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle

Comment: @CoderSpinoza apparently so, and if I were to work on the linux kernel then I would follow that style. Elsewhere, I'd avoid it.

Comment: A lot of C code repos use one line ifs without braces, and it is totally fine.

Answer (score 15):

A `do{}while(0)` allows you to break from the loop:

```
do{
   expr1;
   foo();
   if ( cond )
      break;
   expr2;
   goo(); 
} while (0);
```

It's the same as a simple block `{...}` except that you can break execution when you want with the `break` statement. You couldn't do that in a simple code block, unless you have multiple checks, which can get cumbersome. It still gets executed once, because of the condition `while(0)`.

Comment: ...it does, but please don't...

Comment: It reduces the number of if-else nesting.