# MISRA 19.4 clarification

Tags: c, misra

I want to use the following MACRO in my file

```
#define DO_WAKEUP_SYNCHRONISIEREN proc.id = process_WAKEUP;proc.priority.level = PRIO_AKTIV_1;proc.priority.param=0u;(void)prio_mapF_put_in_matrix(proc)
```

I know that it is a violation of MISRA-C:2004 Rule 19.4 - but I need to use this and to solve the violation.

Is there any way I can use the MACRO and also solve the MISRA-C violation?

MISRA-C:2004 Rule 19.4 is

> C macros shall only expand to a braced initialiser, a constant,
>   a string literal, a parenthesised expression, a type qualifier, a
>   storage class specifier, or a do-while-zero construct.

Comment: better to wrap your macro code in `do {} while(0)` for starters so it's considered as one sole "instruction" in conditions.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre  I get the following message "Violates MISRA 2004 Required Rule 19.4, Disallowed definition for macro 'DO_WAKEUP_SYNCHRONISIEREN'"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it looks like the rule is:

```
#define B A
```

> The above is not a permitted form of macro definition under this rule because A is not a constant, braced initializer, parenthesized expression, type qualifier, storage class specifier or **do-while-zero construct**

```
#define B (A)
```

> The above is permitted. The replacement list is a parenthesised expression.

an extension of this would be (even without MISRA constraints I'd do this, but I just noticed that the rule states it: "do-while-zero construct", IMHO it's not obvious at first glance what "do-while-zero construct" means when you're not aware of that...):

```
#define DO_WAKEUP_SYNCHRONISIEREN do {proc.id = process_WAKEUP;proc.priority.level = PRIO_AKTIV_1;proc.priority.param=0u;(void)prio_mapF_put_in_matrix(proc);} while(0)
```

so the instruction block cannot be "partially called" by constructs like this:

```
if (flag) DO_WAKEUP_SYNCHRONISIEREN;
```

which would give headaches to anyone trying to understand the bug.

And at the same time it forces to add a `;` as opposed to a simple `{}` block. So the macro looks very much like a function call (also read [Why use do { } while (0) in macro definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495962/why-use-do-while-0-in-macro-definition)).

Comment: As an (perhaps interesting) aside, MISRA C:2012 has relaxed this requirement - although personally, I would still advise using braces or parentheses to bound the macro unless otherwise required

Comment: maybe they did so so it was possible to define `case x: do_##x()` stuff... Dunno. This rule sounded like a good idea to me, and every rule has exceptions.

Comment: do while(0) was removed from MISRA-C with version 2012. Earlier MISRA-C recommended using this practice, but it was criticized since do while(0) allows you to write control/loop statements that are not compound statements, which is in turn required by a different MISRA rule. The whole purpose of the do while(0) trick is to allow code such as `if(x) macro(); else`. But MISRA-C compatible code would have to be `if(x) { macro(); }  else`. And so the do-while(0) trick is harmful, as it blocks the compiler from detecting MISRA-C violations.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The whole purpose of the `do while(0)` trick (that's heavily covered here on SO) is to allow block and still force a `;` in the end, which you cannot ensure with `if(x) { macro(); } else`. As you said, there's no perfect world, and sometimes rules contradict each other like you mentionned. Rules are there to be violated with some justification when you know what you're doing.